# How to access appIcons in iOS using privateframewok

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I want to access app icon by using private framework.There is a private framework MobileIcons.framework in iOS, but  I don't know how to use it to get an app icon.

Comment: Your app icon or icon of the other apps ?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore icons of all installed apps in iOS device.